# C# Casting Array and getting information out of an array of objects

Tags: c#, csharpcodeprovider

I am trying to see if I can cast a menu object as food. I will be putting in the interface as I have been advised.

In my buffet code where my Food method is called after adding all the stuff to the menu object, my goal is to pick a random food to eat then return the information.

I was hoping that I could do something like where I got the `mo =(Food) Menu[rand.Next(Menu.Count)];` would allow me to this easily.

I was wrong, I might be overcomplicating this because I was going to return `mo` but every time I try to cast it, it did not work.

Maybe I can use an enumerator or something but it is just very confusing. I think I have the proper thinking of what I want but to express in words is difficult so thank you all for your patience with me. I hope this explains it better:

my Buffet class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;


namespace IronNinja.Models
{
    
    class Buffet
    {
        public List<Food> Foods = new List<Food>();

        public List<Drink> Dranks = new List<Drink>();

        public List<object> Menu = new List<object>();

        //constructor
        public Buffet()
        {
            Menu.Add(new Food("Chicken Pizza", 1000, false, true));
            Menu.Add(new Food("Buffalo Chicken Pizza", 1000, true, false));
            Menu.Add(new Food("Lasagna", 1200, false, true));
            Menu.Add(new Food("Garden Salad WSalad dressing", 700, true, false));
            Menu.Add(new Food("sour patch kids whole box", 700, false, true));
            Menu.Add(new Drink("Rootbeer", 700, false));
            Menu.Add(new Drink("Not Your Father's Rootbeer", 900, false));
        }
        // Add a constructor and Serve method to the Buffet class
        public Food Serve()
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            Food mo =  ((Food) Menu[rand.Next(Menu.Count)]);
            Console.WriteLine(mo);

            return new Food("sour patch kids whole box", 700, false, true);
        }
    }
}
```

My Drink class

```
using IronNinja.Interfaces;
namespace IronNinja.Models
{
    public class Drink : IConsumable
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Calories { get; set; }
        public bool IsSpicy { get; set; }
        public bool IsSweet { get; set; }
       // Implement a GetInfo Method
        public string GetInfo()
        {
            return $"{Name} (Drink).  Calories: {Calories}.  Spicy?: {IsSpicy}, 
             Sweet?: {IsSweet.Equals(true)}";
        }
        // Add a constructor method
        public Drink(string name, int calories, bool spicy)
        {
            Name = name;
            Calories = calories;
            IsSpicy = spicy;
            IsSweet = true;
        }
    }
}
```

my foodclass

```
using IronNinja.Interfaces;
namespace IronNinja.Models
{
    class Food : IConsumable
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Calories { get; set; }
        public bool IsSpicy { get; set; }
        public bool IsSweet { get; set; }
        public string GetInfo()
        {
            return $"{Name} (Food).  Calories: {Calories}.  Spicy?: {IsSpicy}, 
            Sweet?: {IsSweet}";
        }
        public Food(string name, int calories, bool spicy, bool sweet)
        {
            Name = name;
            Calories = calories;
            IsSpicy = spicy;
            IsSweet = sweet;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer with a sample of how to get a random food.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

If you just want to grab a random item that is a food, you can use a Linq expression to get all items that are of the type `Food`.

```
Random rand = new Random();
var foodItems = Menu.OfType<Food>().ToList();
var randomFood = foodItems[rand.Next(foodItems.Count)];
```

I would create an interface called `IMenuItem` that has the shared properties for every type that goes on a menu.

```cs
public interface IMenuItem
{
    string Name { get; }
}
```

Then add that interface to your `Food` and `Drink` classes

```cs
public class Food : IMenuItem
{
    public Food(string name, int calories, bool isSpicy, bool isSweet)
    {
        Name = name;
        Calories = calories;
        IsSpicy = isSpicy;
        IsSweet = isSweet;
    }

    public string Name { get; }
    public int Calories { get; }
    public bool IsSpicy { get; }
    public bool IsSweet { get; }
}

public class Drink: IMenuItem
{
    public Drink(string name, int calories, bool isSpicy)
    {
        Name = name;
        Calories = calories;
        IsSpicy = isSpicy;
    }

    public string Name { get; }
    public int Calories { get; }
    public bool IsSpicy { get; }
}
```

Now you can have a list of menu items and you will be able to access those shared properties without having to cast anything.

```
var menu = new List<IMenuItem>();
menu.Add(new Food("pizza", calories: 300, isSpicy: false, isSweet: true));
menu.Add(new Drink ("coke", calories: 300, isSpicy: false));

foreach(var menuItem in menu)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
}
```

output

```
pizza
coke
```

Also, you can use pattern matching to do things based on what type it actually is.

```
var menu = new List<IMenuItem>();
menu.Add(new Food("pizza", calories: 300, isSpicy: false, isSweet: true));
menu.Add(new Drink("coke", calories: 300, isSpicy: false));

// get random menu item;
var rand = new Random();
var menuItem = menu[rand.Next(menu.Count)];

switch (menuItem)
{
    case Food food: // random item is a food
        Console.WriteLine($"Food Name:{food.Name}, Calories:{food.Calories}, IsSpicy:{food.IsSpicy}, IsSweet:{food.IsSweet}");
        break;
    case Drink drink: // random item is a drink
        Console.WriteLine($"Drink Name:{drink.Name}, Calories:{drink.Calories}, IsSpicy:{drink.IsSpicy}");
        break;
    default: // random item is something else
        Console.WriteLine($"Menu Item Name:{menuItem.Name}");
        break;
}
```

Comment: How would you retrieve Something out of it like the name of the Food because I am having an issue with that

Comment: I showed an example to write out the name of each item in the list.

Comment: Yeah but I don't want to print it out in a for each loop. I am trying to get a randitem and cast it as a Food item I will update and show my code

Comment: Okay, need a clear example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I gave an example of how to pull a random menu item and do something different with the value depending on what kind of menu item it is.

Comment: One thing that confused me is that when you had the IMenuInterface you only had name in it as a string I didn't not realize it would still work the way you had it done thank you so much for this help I will try to implement all that :)

Comment: No problem, I added a way to only get a random Food and ignore drinks at the top. Just have to add `using System.Linq;` to the top.

Comment: can you cast Drink as a food?

Comment: No, that will throw an exception `InvalidCastException`.

Comment: Well this works once again you are my hero thank you so much :)

Comment: No problem, happy to help.